# Installing pyasn to Kali produces error "python 2.7 breaks python-pyasn1 and is installed"

Tags: kali-linux, python, dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -i python-pyasn1_0.4.2-3build1_all.deb
```

I try to depackage this deb, yet I am on kali (debian) I get error

```
python 2.7 breaks python-pyasn1 and is installed
dpkg: error processing package python-pyasn1 (--install):
```

What can I do about this ?

Comment: @Peregrino69 is 100% correct, but just to add a note, you'll find that various distros have dependencies on python2 or python3, so you can run into significant issues, and if you need it for your code, you're almost always better off building on a distro that's compatible, or building python from binaries.

Answer (score 4):

You’re trying to install a Python 2 module, and those aren’t supported any more in current versions of Kali or Debian. The `python2.7` package is still available, but to ensure that obsolete modules aren’t left lying around, it prevents their installation.

If you’re writing new code, you should use Python 3 and [the `python3-pyasn1` package](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/pyasn1) instead; the latter is available in the Kali repositories:

```
sudo apt install python3-pyasn1
```

If you’re trying to get older software to work, you’d be better off using a Python 2 virtual environment and installing the module using `pip`.